# How to install Python3 with putty

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, putty, nas

I have a NAS and I would like to run a python3 program using putty (SSH) but my code is in python3 while the pre-installed version of python there is python 2.7.
How can I install python3 using SSH?

Comment: Which OS is installed?

Comment: On the pc it's windows 10 while on the NAS I wouldn't know how to tell, I can tell you it's a qnap 231p nas, I don't know if it helps...

Comment: To find out you could type: `hostnamectl`or `uname -o` in the putty shell when connected to your NAS. This should print your OS information if it is Linux based.

Comment: Do you have Choco?

Comment: @oliverm uname -o gave me an error, I tried uname -a and this is what it told me: 
Linux NAS3A3E43 4.2.8 #2 SMP Fri Dec 6 13:08:58 CST 2019 armv7l unknown

Comment: @SanjitSarda I do not have Choco but if it is necessary I would be more than happy to install it

Comment: If you install choco it will not only help you install python, but other packages in the future, so I would suggest you install it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As QNAP seems to run their own Linux for their NAS you need to install Python 3 via their App center.

It should be available according to their Release Notes: [1](https://www.qnap.com/en/app_releasenotes/list.php?app_choose=Python3)

There also seems to be a subreddit here: [2](https://www.reddit.com/r/qnap/comments/98wjd6/python_from_the_app_center/)

And a blog about Python on their OS here: [3](http://ilearnblogger.blogspot.com/2015/04/qnaplinux-python-programming-01-setup.html)